# CakePHP Upload plugin – not creating thumbnail

Tags: cakephp, upload

I use the Upload plugin from https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

The problem is, while the main image is uploaded fine, it is not creating thumbnails.

Here is my model code

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                'featured' => '720x400',
                'xsmall' => '98x98',
                'small' => '152x110',
                'medium' => '400x222',
                'large' => '225x145',
                'medium_home' => '232x128',
                'xlarge' => '720x632',
                'editorial' => '199x300',
                'medium_editorial' => '180x249',
                'small_editorial' => '152x211',
                'xsmall_editorial' => '98x136'
            ),
            'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}uploads{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}'
        )
    )
);
```

Any idea what should I change?

Answer (score 1):

Add `'thumbnails' => true` and also `'thumbnailMethod' => 'php'` in you array and the code will look like:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'thumbnails' => true,
           'thumbnailMethod' => 'php',
            'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                'featured' => '720x400',
                'xsmall' => '98x98',
                'small' => '152x110',
                'medium' => '400x222',
                'large' => '225x145',
                'medium_home' => '232x128',
                'xlarge' => '720x632',
                'editorial' => '199x300',
                'medium_editorial' => '180x249',
                'small_editorial' => '152x211',
                'xsmall_editorial' => '98x136'
            ),
            'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}uploads{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}'
        )
    )
);
```

I used the code below and it works fine for me:

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'photo' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'photo_dir'
                ),
                'deleteOnUpdate' => true,
                'thumbnails' => true,
                'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                    '64x64' => '64x64'
                ),
                'thumbnailMethod' => 'php'
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: NTkhan – thank you for your suggestion but it is not working.

Comment: I have added the code in my answer which I used and works fine.

Comment: gd is enabled or not in php.ini if not then enable it by removing `;` from `;extension=php_gd.dll` in php.ini in case of `'thumbnailMethod' => 'php'`

Comment: NTKhan – I have tried set `thumbNailMethod` to `php` but it still doesn't works